# export to Beamer gets slower and slower

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

My presentation has like 30 slides, nothing fancy, mostly a couple of bullet points on each frame and in total like 10 small images. Still the export to beamer, i.e. a pdf takes like 10 seconds and Emacs freezes for the time.

Can anyone tell me why that is or how to fix it?

Comment: The images should be cached, so exporting again should avoid regeneration. Is  that noticeably faster? You might also want to time individual steps, e.g. going to a LaTeX beamer file, rather than directly to PDF. Or you can [profile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html#Profiling) the code, although that's probably best done after you narrowed down the cause of the slowdown. BTW, your title says "slower and slower" but you don't provide any evidence of that in the body of the question: when/how/how much faster was it and when/how/how much did it slow down?

Comment: it is hard to measure, I guess. Comes down to a feeling ob being unresponsive and taking like 10 seconds until Emacs is responsive again. I observed the same with vanilla Emacs -Q, so the config cannot be the problem. Emacs version is 26.3 and Org version is 9.3.7

Comment: You can forget my comment about the images above: it is nonsense.

Comment: A 34-slide document (with no images) took about 7 seconds on my (very old) workstation, from pressing `C-c C-e l O` to the pdf popping up, so I'd say it's about par for the course. Timing individual steps: org->tex is less than 1 sec, tex->pdf from the command line took about 2 seconds. So there is a substantial overhead that emacs imposes. Using `elp` to instrument the `org` prefix shows that `org-latex-compile` took almost 7 seconds. So at least you are not alone :-)

Comment: thank you for your effort. All right then, I just wished it would be more snappy ;)

Comment: BTW, I am running with uncompiled Org mode and there is some overhead from `elp` itself. Repeating the `elp` step with compiled Org mode shows that `org-latex-compile` still takes 5.5 seconds, so it helps a bit but does not really make any snappier.